# How to do damage with SQL by adding to the end of a statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, security, sql-injection

Perhaps I am not creative or knowledgeable enough with SQL... but it looks like there is no way to do a DROP TABLE or DELETE FROM within a SELECT without the ability to start a new statement.

Basically, we have a situation where our codebase has some gigantic, "less-than-robust" SQL generation component that never uses prepared statements and we now have an API that interacts with this legacy component.

Right now we can modify a query by appending to the end of it, but have been **unable to insert any semicolons**.  Thus, we can do something like this:

`/query?[...]&location_ids=loc1')%20or%20L1.ID%20in%20('loc2`

which will result in this

`SELECT...WHERE L1.PARENT_ID='1' and L1.ID IN ('loc1') or L1.ID in ('loc2');...`

This is just one example.

Basically we can append pretty much anything to the end of any/most generated SQL queries, less adding a semicolon.

Any ideas on how this could potentially do some damage?  Can you add something to the end of a SQL query that deletes from or drops tables?  Or create a query so absurd that it takes up all CPU and never completes?

Comment: There are numerous threads regarding SQL Injections, you may wish to read some previous search results [by clicking here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection) or searching manually.

Comment: You state that the result of the query sting addition would result in "SELECT...WHERE L1.PARENT_ID='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001' and L1.ID IN ('loc1') or L1.ID in ('loc2');"  but if you notice there is a semi-colon at the end.  How did the semi-colon get there?

Comment: The SQL component adds it to the end.

Comment: so if I construct query string like this /query?[...]&location_ids=loc1');  What happens to the semicolon that I put in the querystring?

Comment: The server throws an exception.  `com.company.nbi.exceptions.ApplicationException: 0x1F615:EXCEPTION OCCURRED RUNNING SQL QUERY:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "')"`

Answer (score 0):

You said that this:

```
/query?[...]&location_ids=loc1')%20or%20L1.ID%20in%20('loc2
```

will result in this:

```
SELECT...WHERE L1.PARENT_ID='1' and L1.ID IN ('loc1') or L1.ID in ('loc2');
```

so it looks like this:

```
/query?[...]&location_ids=');DROP%20TABLE users;--
```

will result in this:

```
SELECT...WHERE L1.PARENT_ID='1' and L1.ID IN ('');DROP TABLE users;--');
```

which is a SELECT, a DROP and a comment.

Comment: The SQL is semi-sanitized and semicolons are removed.  I have been unable to insert a semicolon in the statement; I was more curious on what you could tack on (like with a JOIN or UNION) that might do something interesting.  But still going to try to get a semicolon in there somehow (reading the link @Zarthus posted above.)

Answer (score 0):

If it’s not possible to inject another statement, you limited to the existing statement and its abilities.

Like in this case, if you are limited to `SELECT` and you know where the injection happens, have a look at [PostgreSQL’s `SELECT` syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html) to see what your options are. Since you’re injecting into the [`WHERE` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WHERE), you can only inject additional conditions or other clauses that are allowed after the `WHERE` clause.

If the result of the `SELECT` is returned back to the user, you may want to add your own `SELECT` with a [`UNION` operation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION). However, PostgreSQL requires compatible data types for corresponding columns:

> The two `SELECT` statements that represent the direct operands of the `UNION` must produce the same number of columns, and corresponding columns must be of compatible data types.

So you would need to know the number and data types of the columns of the original `SELECT` first.

The number of columns can be detected with the [`ORDER BY` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) by specifying the column number like `ORDER BY 3`, which would order the result by the values of the third column. If the specified column does not exist, the query will fail.

Now after determining the number of columns, you can inject a `UNION SELECT` with the appropriate number of columns with an `null` value for each column of your `UNION SELECT`:

```
 loc1') UNION SELECT null,null,null,null,null --
```

Now you determine the types of each column by using a different value for each column one by one. If the types of a column are incompatible, you may an error that hints the expected data type like:

> ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer
>   ERROR: UNION types text and integer cannot be matched

After you have determined enough column types (one column may be sufficient when it’s one that is presented the user), you can change your `SELECT` to select whatever you want.

Comment: If the OP could have figured how to do this from the Postgres documentation, he would have posted the answer himself. Which "additional conditions or other clauses that are allowed after the WHERE clause" can he use to modify the database, access data that he shouldn't, or do something else harmful?

Comment: @JaneGoodall “[The SQL is semi-sanitized and semicolons are removed. I have been unable to insert a semicolon in the statement; I was more curious on what you could tack on (like with a JOIN or UNION) that might do something interesting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23687813/how-to-do-damage-with-sql-by-adding-to-the-end-of-a-statement/23693334?noredirect=1#comment36396104_23687913)” – If you can’t enter another statement, you are limited to what `SELECT` offers.

Comment: That's his question, though. He wants to know how can he do damage since he can't enter another statement. If he can use `UNION SELECT`S to do damage, what are some that will?

Comment: @JaneGoodall Pretty sure his point is that you can access data that you shouldn't be able to access.

Comment: @JaneGoodall Damage is not just ‘something gets destroyed’.

Comment: No one ever said that. Do you have any examples of queries that would let him "access data that he shouldn't, or do something else harmful"?

Comment: @JaneGoodall With an injected `UNION SELECT` an attacker can select *any* data the current database user has access to. This certainly includes at least the entire web application’s data.